# How to open a nonmodal child dialog that gets focused again when parent is refocused

Tags: winforms

I work on an MDI application where all Forms are opened as separate tabs.

I would like to open a dialog (non-modal) from one tabbed form which then sticks with this form.

I would like to have the dialog hide when another tab (form) is navigated to. But as soon as I navigate back to the form which opened the dialog, the dialog should be still visible as well.

Do I have to do this by hand? If I just show the dialog form like

```
form.Show(this)
```

where "this" is the parent form, the dialog just goes to the background when navigating away and is not focused again when navigating to the parent.

Comment: Do you actually have a MDI application, or are you mocking it? If your Forms set the `MdiParent` Property, after that the Forms are parented with the `MdiClient` of the MDI Form. So, when you call `form.Show(this)`, `this` (the Owner) will be actually the Parent of the `MdiClient`, hence the MDI Form itself (because `MdiClient` is not a Form). So a Form shown with `Show(this)` in a MDI Child Form will be shown on top of all the child Forms (since the Owner is the MDI Parent).

Comment: On the other hand, if you write, e.g., `var f = new Form() { TopLevel = false, Parent = this};
f.Show(); f.BringToFront();` then...